# Matching a vector element with another vector values

Tags: r

Can someone correct me in trying to read indexes of values from a vector that match my present value. Thanks in advance...

```
lat_Array<-c(seq(90,-89.95,by=-0.05))
a<-c(3.7,90) 
match(a[1],lat_Array) # Returns NA, despite index 1727 having the value 3.7
match(a[2],lat_Array) # Surprisingly works and returns 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see the [R FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) with regards to equality of floating point numbers.

One method to find the closest match is:

```
which.min(abs(lat_Array - a[1]))
##  [1] 1727
lat_Array[1727]
##  [1] 3.7
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to the cause of issue and for providing the answer.. :)